# Getting Started template - Unable to find package Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Nuget, Sitecore

Tags: installation, docker

[Getting Started template Sitecore 10](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html) While running up.ps1 getting below errors:

```
C:\build\Directory.Build.targets : warning : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
C:\build\Directory.Build.targets : warning : Unable to load the service index for source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json.
C:\build\Directory.Build.targets : error : Unable to find package Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Nuget, Sitecore
C:\build\Directory.Build.targets : error : C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.
C:\build\Directory.Build.targets : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions/2.0.79' specified could not be found. [C:\build\src\platform\Platform.csproj]
C:\build\Directory.Build.targets : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions/2.0.79' specified could not be found. [C:\build\src\rendering\RenderingHost.csproj]
```

See more details
[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: As mentioned in this thread did you add the DNS in the configuration file https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30201/nuget-restore-not-working-when-building-sitecore-images?