# NuGet Restore not Working When Building Sitecore Images

Tags: docker, nuget

I'm trying to spin up the following Sitecore environment using docker:

https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/tree/develop/custom-images

I've already run the Init.ps1 script that fills in all the variables, certificates, Sitecore license and so on... but when I run docker-compose up -d it says the following during the Nuget restore command:
[image: nuget restore error]

Yesterday I've tried to fix that but I ended up messing with my machine, then I re-imaged it, and even doing that, with the machine all empty, the error persists. I couldn't find any relevant content about that on the internet.
I don't know why the  MSBuild auto-detection is trying to use that path that doesn't have the MSbuild installed.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've faced the same issue weeks ago and I fixed it by adding a google DNS (8.8.8.8) on my docker settings as on the print screen below, try to do the same.
[image: Docker Engine Configurations]

Answer (score 1):

Besides solution suggested by Eduardo, you can also try disconnecting any VPN you are connected to and then running the script. I have seen similar error due to multiple reasons and disconnecting from VPN was one of the solutions.